# Horizontally center-align a bootstrap button with accompanying text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to horizontally center-align a bootstrap button with accompanying text. But am not getting the expected output. Could someone tell me why its not centering?

```
<div class="col-md-12 well">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Sign in via google</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <span><em> Already have an account? Login</em></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gvI9dawzFR3pfPVqIeWy?p=preview). In smaller screens it works as expected. But in larger screens it's not aligned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around I found a solution..Its not a bootstrap solution. But its only few lines of css. If anyone found a bootsrap way post here and I will change the accepted answer. Thank you.

```
    <div class="row well row-centered">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
        <h2 class="btn btn-warning btn-lg center-block">Sign in via google</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-centered" >
        <span><em> Already have an account?Login
       </div>
      </div>
```

here is the custom css

```
  /* centered columns styles */
  .row-centered {
    text-align:center;
  }
  .col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `col-md-offset-3` along with `col-md-6` to center align your content:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
   ...
</div>
```

Further more, set `text-center` class on the outside div and not on span tag:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
    <em> Already have an account? Login</em>
</div>
```

See fiddle [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOavQ).

Comment: yes adding 'text-center' outside is making the text centered. But its sligned to the top of the panel. How can I keep the text and button in center of the panel properly aligned?? Also I dont want to use col-md-offset as I want the button and text in same line in the panel in big screens..

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```css
.flex-centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 31px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12 well">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <h2 class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Sign in via google</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="flex-centered">
      <em> Already have an account? Login</em>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use div outside of span tag

```
<div  style="text-align:center;" ><span class="text-center"><em> Already have an account? Login</em></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
      <h2 class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Sign in via google</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <span><em> Already have an account? Login</em></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xURcw8dxaAifv7wem9mx?p=preview)

Comment: its pushing the text to bottom..I am looking for horizontal alignment as u can see in my plunker